# Border bottom in UIView Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiview, border

I have an UIView and I would like to add a gray border bottom, how can I do that in swift, I new in this.

`@IBOutlet weak var viewTopControl: UIView!`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to do it by programatically, you can add extension to UIView like following.

```
extension UIView {

    enum ViewSide {
        case Left, Right, Top, Bottom
    }

    func addBorder(toSide side: ViewSide, withColor color: CGColor, andThickness thickness: CGFloat) {

        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color

        switch side {
        case .Left: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: thickness, height: frame.height); break
        case .Right: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.maxX, y: frame.minY, width: thickness, height: frame.height); break
        case .Top: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: thickness); break
        case .Bottom: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.maxY, width: frame.width, height: thickness); break
        }

        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
viewTopControl.addBorder(toSide: .Bottom, withColor: UIColor.redColor().CGColor, andThickness: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is s generalized Swift extension to create border for any UIView subclass:

```
extension UIView {
 func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}

func addRightBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - width, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}

func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}

func addLeftBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version here

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    // Example use: myView.addBorder(toSide: .Left, withColor: UIColor.redColor().CGColor, andThickness: 1.0)

    enum ViewSide {
        case left, right, top, bottom
    }

    func addBorder(toSide side: ViewSide, withColor color: CGColor, andThickness thickness: CGFloat) {

        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color

        switch side {
        case .left: border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: thickness, height: self.frame.size.height)
        case .right: border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - thickness, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: thickness, height: self.frame.size.height)
        case .top: border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.size.width, height: thickness)
        case .bottom: border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.size.height - thickness, width: self.frame.size.width, height: thickness)
        }
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
view.addBorder(toSide: .bottom, withColor: UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, andThickness: 0.2)
```